# How to get dynamic fields from a template using jinja2?

Tags: flask, jinja2, templating-engine

for template: "Hi {{ name }}, whats your {{ age }}", I need dynamic fields as ['name', 'age']

Comment: Your question is how to pass the `name` and `age`  to templates from flask function ?

Comment: No, suppose I don't know what the template will be, how to pass correct context.

Comment: Still not clear... Can you explain more about what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: If you dont know the content of a template, how to get all dynamic fields, for example in the above example for template "Hi {{ name }}, whats your {{ age }}", dynamic fields are ['name', 'age']. Now if you want know, whats the content is, how to get the dynamic fields.

Comment: Just saying, If you pass with dict then the hole process is very easy.

Comment: But you can still get the items using `var.0` and so on...